# Use multiple WhereIn Clause Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, where-in

I need to use multiple `WhereIn` Clauses with `OR` in a query.. So I was doing it something like below... It is not working and I am getting an empty result

```
orWhereIn('cat', $array)
orWhereIn('cat_a', $array)
orWhereIn('child_a', $array)
```

is it possible? .. I have looked over the internet for solution but could find anything

I am using Laravel 4.2 ..  thanks in advance

**My Full Query**

Note: if I use single `whereIn` clause.. it works absolutely fine..

```
$query = Product::query();
$query->orWhereIn('category_id', $ids);
$query->orWhereIn('category_id_2', $ids);
$query->orWhereIn('category_id_3', $ids);
$query->orderBy('price_for_sorting', 'ASC');
$products = $query->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. Just make sure that if you have another where clause that's meant to be an AND, that you have your query nested properly.

Comment: I am only using paginate() after this `query`

Comment: Can you show your full query?

Comment: i've edited my question @anyber

Comment: If you use `get()` instead of `paginate()`, do you get the results?

Comment: `paginate` is used to limit the data.. can we use `get` in this case ? @aynber

Comment: Trying `get` instead of `paginate` will tell you if it's an issue with the pagination or with the retrieval in general. Either way, though, it should work. You can verify the query by using `Log::info($query->toSql());` right before the paginate call, and check your Laravel log to see if the query looks correct. You can [edit] your question and paste it here, if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks alot.. I'll try for sure..